# How to check if I already sent anybody friend request on facebook using graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any method in facebook graph API to check if I already sent a friend request to a user?

Something like UserId_1 = 76, UserId_2 = 55

Already_sent_friend_request?(user_id=76) = true

Already_sent_friend_request?(user_id=55) = false

Comment: Graph API `user` object has a `friendrequests` connection, but that is only for incoming friend request (send to the current user) – maybe possible with the FQL [friend_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend_request) table, that can be queried by `uid_to`, but you’ll have to check if `read_requests` gives you access.

Comment: Thanks. Atlast fb itself added this option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook itself added an option for seeing sent/pending friend requests.